# Mistake in uploaded file type after revision

Tags: paper-submission, editors

I have revised my manuscript in Elsevier's journal and uploaded it along with the point-by-point reviewer comments responding. I found I have made a mistake in uploading the file.

There is the list of file types need to submit in the author page as follows:
1. Manuscript (revised manuscript)
2. Respond to reviewer
3. Revised manuscript with Changes marker

For the file type number 3, I uploaded the wrong file, which lists the changed in manuscript in detail instead of the full manuscript with changes marked.

I wonder Do I need to write an email to the editor to explain about that? Anyone has experience in this problem please give me the advice.

One more question: how long should we wait for the status change from "with journal" to "with editor" or "under review" for the revised manuscript?

Comment: You can email the editor.  However, the admin person processing your paper may notice the mistake and send it back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Mistakes can happen.
You should email the editor or they might notice it and ask you to upload the correct one.

"One more question: how long should we wait for the status change from "with journal" to "with editor" or "under review" for the revised manuscript? "
It depends on the journal, you should check the journal website for more information or ask directly the editor.